# Create like a progress bar to check data state using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

The public idea is display the state of current data immediately.
I will give an example to illustrate the idea.

A simple example:-

**PHP:**

```
// target.php - this function will be called using ajax
function immediately() {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
// this code will get the value of $i immediately
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "pathToFile/immediately/", // Note: I'm use the style of a php framework to access to method.
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

What I want is display the value of `$i` in every change.

**Like the following:**

```
$i = 1 
Display it in the #result element.
$i = 2
Display it in the #result element.
and so on
```

I don't want `$i` to wait until access to last value and then display it.
**Note:** the previous example is just a simple example to explain my idea.

Comment: i dont get the question, you want $i to retain its value? for all users or current user?

Comment: Actually see it now, Ajax is not designed for a constant connection , you need websockets or get js to do the processing (use ajax to pull the db information and process with js)

Comment: @David: I want an idea to do that if possible.

Comment: Its not as simple as some sample code, you need to set up the server to listen for information but heres a link to a php class https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets  there is prob some information there somewhere to set up your server. If not google it.